# Registering network adapter changes in real time

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32, connectivity

For a Python application, I want to react to changes in network adapters as quickly as possible, e.g. whenever an adapter is connected or disconnected or the IP address of any adapter changes. I'm on Windows 10.

My current approach is to use `EvtSubscribe` from the [`win32evtlog`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32evtlog.html) module to watch for new entries to the event log `Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational`. However, IP address changes seem to take anywhere from 1 to 10 seconds to be registered this way and connecting/disconnecting an adapter is about a second slower than the reaction time seen on the icons in `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections`.

Is there any way I could react more quickly to these changes? I'd also welcome explanations as to why a quicker reaction would **not** be possible.

Comment: I test `EvtSubscribe`, yes, there seems several seconds delay between what you see from control panel and event received in my code. Could you share your expectation and the resons for it?

Comment: I don't have any different expectation towards `EvtSubscribe`, I'm looking for an alternative solution that enables me to react to network adapter changes more quickly (with smaller delay), if there is any.

Comment: You can query NetworkAdapter information via CIM to see if it helps. Refer to ["CIM_NetworkAdapter class"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/cim-networkadapter) and ["Using WMI"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/using-wmi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found and tried three approaches myself, presented in the following. Note that they are all Windows-specific. I tested changes to network adapters being connected by plugging my ethernet cable in/out as well as enabling/disabling WLAN. Connecting an adapter always takes a while to be registered, the Windows GUI in `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections` needs about three seconds as well. Nothing to be done there, I suppose.

### NetworkChange

Using [`pythonnet`](https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/) allows importing [`NetworkChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange) from `System.Net.NetworkInformation` in the .NET API. The `NetworkAddressChanged` event can be used to be notified on address **and** adapter connection information. The `NetworkAvailabilityChanged` event will only fire if no adapter is connected to a network anymore, which may or may not be what you want.
This approach gave me the best results overall: Address changes and adapter disconnect take less than a second to be registered, connecting an adapter takes about 3.5 seconds. Python code is similar to the usage shown in the Microsoft Docs. However, the event does not fire on address changes made to disconnected adapters and DNS server changes.

### Watching the registry

Using `win32api`'s [`RegNotifyChangeKeyValue`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__RegNotifyChangeKeyValue_meth.html) allows listening for changes in the subkeys of registry entry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces` (for address changes) and `...\Tcpip\Parameters\DNSRegisteredAdapters` (for connect / disconnect). It appears that the latter entry does not actually store the information itself, but is changed as a side effect. Another drawback is that there might be changes in the registry keys that have nothing to do with the changes we are looking for.
This approach was almost instantaneous to report address changes (even quicker than the NetworkChange approach). Adapter connection was also a bit quicker at about 3 seconds. However, adapter disconnection is much slower and takes a bit over 3 seconds to be registered. Example code:

```
import win32api
import win32event
import win32con

def registry_wait():
    watchflags = win32api.REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_NAME | win32api.REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_SET
    if_key = win32api.RegOpenKey(win32con.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces')
    if_evt = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
    win32api.RegNotifyChangeKeyValue(if_key, True, watchflags, if_evt, True)
    dnsada_key = win32api.RegOpenKey(win32con.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\DNSRegisteredAdapters')
    dnsada_evt = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
    win32api.RegNotifyChangeKeyValue(dnsada_key, True, watchflags, dnsada_evt, True)
    while True:
        ret_code = win32event.WaitForMultipleObjects([if_evt, dnsada_evt], False, win32event.INFINITE)
        if ret_code == win32con.WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0:
            print('IP address info changed') # do something
            win32event.ResetEvent(if_evt)
            win32api.RegNotifyChangeKeyValue(if_key, True, watchflags, if_evt, True)
        elif ret_code == win32con.WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
            print('Adapter info changed') # do something else
            win32event.ResetEvent(dnsada_evt)
            win32api.RegNotifyChangeKeyValue(dnsada_key, True, watchflags, dnsada_evt, True)
        else:
            break # set a timeout in WaitForMultipleObjects above
    win32api.RegCloseKey(dnsada_key)
    win32api.RegCloseKey(if_key)
```

### Watching the Event Log

This is the method mentioned in the question, using `EvtSubscribe` to listen to the `Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational` event log. This was slower than the other two approaches in almost every regard. I saw address changes take anywhere from 2 to 10 seconds to get logged, but around 6 or 7 seconds most of the time. Connecting an adapter consistently takes about 4 seconds. Disconnecting an adapter takes a bit over 1 seconds, beating the registry approach in that regard. NetworkChange approach is always quicker though.